# Вложеная фильтрация массива Java Script

Tags: javascript, typescript

Я имею следующий массив объектов:

```
rows = [
  {
    name: "user1",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    previlege: "Reportering"
  },
  {
    name: "user3",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  }
]
```

И другой массив объектов:

```
selected = [
  {
    name: "user1",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    previlege: "Reportering"
  },
]
```

Мне нужно отфильтровать первый массив удалив все совпадения с вторим. То есть я должен получить

```
rows = [
  {
    name: "user3",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  }
]
```

Я пробую сделать это так:

```
this.array = this.rows.filter((current)=>
  JSON.stringify(current) !== JSON.stringify(this.selected[0])
);
```

Но логически удаляется только первая запись.
Я понимаю, что мне нужно что-то вроде вложенной функции filter или просто вложений цикл for чтоб пройтись по массиве selected, но все мои попытки не увенчались успехом. Помогите мне отфильтровать этот массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, надо в массиве selected поискать entry,

вашу идею можно переписать вот так:

```js
const rows = [
  {
    name: "user1",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    previlege: "Reportering"
  },
  {
    name: "user3",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  }
]
const selected = [
  {
    name: "user1",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    previlege: "Reportering"
  },
]
console.log(rows.filter(current=>
  {
    const currentString = JSON.stringify(current); //небольшая оптимизация
    return !selected.some(entry=> JSON.stringify(entry) === currentString);
  }
));
```

но эта реализация завязана на порядок ключей,в хроме это не сработает если перевернуть инициализацию свойств. 
Для честного сравнения, нужно быть намного более аккуратным:

```js
const rows = [{
    name: "user1",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  },
  {
    previlege: "Reportering",
    name: "user2",
    struct: {
      a: 1,
      b: "a"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "user3",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  }
]
const selected = [{
    name: "user1",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    previlege: "Reportering",
    struct: {
      a: 1,
      b: "a"
    }

  },
];
console.log(rows.filter(current => !selected.some(entry => deepEq(entry, current))));

function deepEq(a, b) {
  const keysA = Object.keys(a);
  const keysB = Object.keys(b);
  if (keysA.length !== keysB.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return !keysA.some(keyA =>
    typeof a[keyA] !== "object" && a[keysA] !== null 
      ? a[keyA] !== b[keyA] 
      : !deepEq(a[keyA], b[keyA])); //рекурсия для объектов
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто отфильтровать первый массив, проверяя, нет ли похожих данных во втором. Я использовал поиск по именю юзера с помощью [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control):

```js
var rows = [
  {
    name: "user1",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    previlege: "Reportering"
  },
  {
    name: "user3",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  }
];

var selected = [
  {
    name: "user1",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    previlege: "Reportering"
  },
]

var array = rows.filter(r => !selected.some(s => s.name == r.name));


console.log(array);
```

Говоря о вашей реализации - вы фильтровали массив на совпадения с **нулевым элементом** (`JSON.stringify(this.selected[0])`)

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто перебрать каждое значение с каждым, цикл в цикле, но это будет не самое быстрое решение, и пойдет только если ваши массивы не очень большие и производительность не очень важна:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   for (var n = 0; n < selected.length; n++) {
        //compare arrays here
        If(rows[i] ==selected[n]){
             return 'arrays are equal'
         }
}
}
```